# Recursive inorder traversal of a binary search tree

Tags: recursion, rust

I want to implement a recursive inorder in a binary search tree (BST). I built a tree using two structs: `Node` and `Tree`. My code has not worked so far, mainly because of a type mismatch in `Node::inorder`.

```
pub struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

pub struct Tree<T> {
    root: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T: Ord> Tree<T> {
    /// Creates an empty tree
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Tree { root: None }
    }

    pub fn inorder(&self) -> Vec<&T> {
        self.root.as_ref().map(|n| n.inorder()).unwrap() // how to pass result ?
    }
}

impl<T: Ord> Node<T> {
    pub fn inorder(&self) -> Vec<&T> {
        let mut result: Vec<&T> = Vec::new();

        match *self {
            None => return result,

            Some(ref node) => {
                let left_vec = node.left.inorder();
                result.extend(left_vec);
                result.extend(node.value);
                let right_vec = node.right.inorder();
                result.extend(right_vec);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error report:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:27:13
   |
27 |             None => return result,
   |             ^^^^ expected struct `Node`, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `Node<T>`
   = note:    found type `std::option::Option<_>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:29:13
   |
29 |             Some(ref node) => {
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Node`, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `Node<T>`
   = note:    found type `std::option::Option<_>`
```

In `Node::inorder`, I want to return a empty vector if a node does not exist; if the node does exist, I want to grow the vector inorder and recur. 
The `match` doesn't work between a `Node` and `Option`, but I am not sure how to bridge between them.

Comment: You should upgrade your version of Rust to get the improved error messages. I've edited this question with them as they are also easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there's confusion about where the options are:

```
impl<T: Ord> Node<T> {
    pub fn inorder(&self) -> Vec<&T> {
    //...
    match *self {
```

Here, `self` is a `Node<T>`, not an option.  Instead, `self.left` and `self.right` are options.

This compiles (until lack of `main()`):

```
pub fn inorder(&self) -> Vec<&T> {

    let mut result: Vec<&T> = Vec::new();

    if let Some(ref left) = self.left {
        let left_vec = left.inorder();
        result.extend(left_vec);
    }
    result.push(&self.value);
    if let Some(ref right) = self.right {
        let right_vec = right.inorder();
        result.extend(right_vec);
    }
    result
}
```

I also added the return, and fixed `result.extend(self.value)` to instead `push` a reference.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=76f0b92a07e0ed0765022f154644780d&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 4):

[Chris Emerson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40945796/155423) is correct, but I'd advocate for a more memory efficient version that always appends to the same vector. This prevents excessive copying of the values.

```
impl<T> Tree<T> {
    pub fn inorder(&self) -> Vec<&T> {
        let mut nodes = Vec::new();
        if let Some(ref root) = self.root {
            root.inorder(&mut nodes);
        }
        nodes
    }
}

impl<T: Ord> Node<T> {
    pub fn inorder<'a>(&'a self, result: &mut Vec<&'a T>) {
        if let Some(ref left) = self.left {
            left.inorder(result);
        }
        result.push(&self.value);
        if let Some(ref right) = self.right {
            right.inorder(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've removed the `: Ord` restriction as it's not needed for traversal.

Even better would be to create an iterator that traverses inorder, then you could just call `collect`.