# How do I flatten a recursive structure using recursive iterators?

Tags: recursion, rust, flatten

I'm trying to flatten a recursive structure but I'm having trouble with recursive iterators.

Here's what the struct looks like:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct C {
    name: String,
    vb: Option<Vec<B>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct B {
    c: Option<C>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct A {
    vb: Option<Vec<B>>,
    flat_c: Option<Vec<C>>,
}
```

My plan is to traverse the `vb` vector and flatten it into `flat_c`. I want it to look like this, or at least, be a `Vec<String>`:

```
Some([
    C {
        name: "foo",
        vb: None,
    },
    C {
        name: "bar",
        vb: None,
    },
    C {
        name: "fizz",
        vb: None,
    },
    C {
        name: "buzz",
        vb: None,
    },
])
```

Here what I managed to do, somewhat flattening the struct, but only for the last element, as the recursion is not implemented.

```
impl A {
    fn flat_c(self) -> Self {
        let fc: Vec<C> = self
            .vb
            .clone()
            .unwrap()
            .iter()
            .flat_map(|x| x.c.as_ref().unwrap().vb.as_ref().unwrap().iter())
            .cloned()
            .map(|x| x.c.unwrap())
            .collect();

        Self {
            flat_c: Some(fc),
            ..self
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        vb: Some(vec![
            B {
                c: Some(C {
                    name: "foo".to_string(),
                    vb: Some(vec![B {
                        c: Some(C {
                            name: "bar".to_string(),
                            vb: None,
                        }),
                    }]),
                }),
            },
            B {
                c: Some(C {
                    name: "fiz".to_string(),
                    vb: Some(vec![B {
                        c: Some(C {
                            name: "buzz".to_string(),
                            vb: None,
                        }),
                    }]),
                }),
            },
        ]),
        flat_c: None,
    };

    let a = a.flat_c();
    println!("a: {:#?}", a);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d55f6bdedfddd639c5dcd29eb15ce040)

The output for `flat_c`:

```
Some([
    C {
        name: "bar",
        vb: None,
    },
    C {
        name: "buzz",
        vb: None,
    },
])
```

I haven't dived into the `Iterator` trait implementation that might be required for this problem.

How would I tackle this problem? Maybe using a `fold`? Perhaps a recursive approach is not even needed? I'm at loss.

Comment: With a generator, that would be easy, but I have no idea about how to do it elegantly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good idea to be familiar with common data structures. You have a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), and there are several ways [to traverse a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). You haven't precisely specified which method to use, so I chose one arbitrarily that's easy to implement.

The key here is to implement an iterator that keeps track of some state: all of the nodes yet to be visited. On each call to `Iterator::next`, we take the next value, save aside any new nodes to visit, and return the value.

Once you have the iterator, you can `collect` it into a `Vec`.

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

impl IntoIterator for A {
    type IntoIter = IntoIter;
    type Item = String;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        IntoIter {
            remaining: self.vb.into_iter().flatten().collect(),
        }
    }
}

struct IntoIter {
    remaining: VecDeque<B>,
}

impl Iterator for IntoIter {
    type Item = String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.remaining.pop_front().and_then(|b| {
            b.c.map(|C { name, vb }| {
                self.remaining.extend(vb.into_iter().flatten());

                name
            })
        })
    }
}

fn to_strings(a: A) -> Vec<String> {
    a.into_iter().collect()
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct A {
    vb: Option<Vec<B>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct B {
    c: Option<C>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct C {
    name: String,
    vb: Option<Vec<B>>,
}

fn main() {
    let example: A = A {
        vb: Some(vec![
            B {
                c: Some(C {
                    name: "Hello ".to_string(),
                    vb: None,
                }),
            },
            B {
                c: Some(C {
                    name: "World!".to_string(),
                    vb: None,
                }),
            },
        ]),
    };
    println!("The example struct: {:?}", example);
    //clone a copy for a second example, because to_strings() takes ownership of the example A struct
    let receipt: A = example.clone();
    println!("Iterated: {:?}", to_strings(example));
    // another example of using to_strings()
    println!(
        "As a string: {:?}",
        to_strings(receipt).into_iter().collect::<String>()
    );
}
```

From here, it should be straight-forward to create an iterator of `B` if that's what you need. Having all of the `None` values seemed silly, so I left them out and directly returned `String`s.

I also made this a by-value iterator. You could follow the same pattern to create an iterator that returned references to the `B` / `String` and only clone them as needed.

See also:

- [How to implement Iterator and IntoIterator for a simple struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30218886/155423)
- [Implement IntoIterator for binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43833588/155423)
- [Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423)
- [Recursive inorder traversal of a binary search tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40944473/155423)

Comment: Thanks, I had the feeling I needed to implement some trait to make it more elegant.

And many thanks for the many resources.

Answer (score 2):

There is my solution:

```
impl C {
    fn flat(&self) -> Vec<C> {
        let mut result = Vec::new();
        result.push(C {
            name: self.name.clone(),
            vb: None,
        });
        if self.vb.is_some() {
            result.extend(
                (self.vb.as_ref().unwrap().iter())
                    .flat_map(|b| b.c.as_ref().map(|c| c.flat()).unwrap_or(Vec::new())),
            );
        }
        return result;
    }
}

impl A {
    fn flat_c(self) -> Self {
        let fc = (self.vb.as_ref().unwrap().iter())
            .flat_map(|b| b.c.as_ref().unwrap().flat())
            .collect();

        Self {
            flat_c: Some(fc),
            ..self
        }
    }
}
```

It adds `flat` function for `C` because the `C` is the source of the recursion and only this struct may properly handle it.

Because of those `Option`s it looks scary and there is hard to deal with cryptic error messages. This solution supposes that all `b.c`s of initial `a` is not a `None`. Otherwise, it will panic. My advice is to avoid using `Option<Vec>` and use just empty vector instead of `None`.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=09ea11342cdd733b03172c0fc13c85fd

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it's what I was looking for.

I'll validate your answer as soon as I played a little bit with your solution.

Comment: I finally went for Shepmaster's solution, as I find the Iterator impl more flexible, yours is valid non the less.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want the result of "traverse the `vb` vector and flatten it into `flat_c`" to be, but here's a slightly simpler example of flattening a recursive structure, using [`once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/fn.once.html) for the value that corresponds to the current node, [`chain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain) to concatenate it with its children and [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) to flatten everything:

```
use std::iter::once;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    name: String,
    children: Vec<S>,
}

impl S {
    fn flat(self) -> Vec<String> {
        once(self.name)
            .chain(self.children.into_iter().flat_map(|c| c.flat()))
            .collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S {
        name: "parent".into(),
        children: vec![
            S {
                name: "child 1".into(),
                children: vec![],
            },
            S {
                name: "child 2".into(),
                children: vec![],
            },
        ],
    };
    println!("s: {:?}", s);
    println!("flat: {:?}", s.flat());
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ddeaceb35eff4ffa049f4ce87d109f75)

Comment: This is a nice example of flattening a struct, (and will probably be very useful to someone) but does not work with the struct provided in the question.

Comment: Alternative playground link https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ddeaceb35eff4ffa049f4ce87d109f75